# Recursive square root inside square root problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, nested-radicals

I have been debating this issue for days:

I can't find a recursive function of this equation:

$\large{\sqrt{2+\pi \sqrt{3+\pi\sqrt{4+\pi\sqrt{5+\dotsb}}}}}$

has been trying to find a solution this for days now, is what I have achieved so far:

$f(n)=\sqrt{2 f(n-1)}, f(1)=\sqrt{2}$

Unfortunately, I do not know how to move forward,
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as
$$
f\left(n\right)=\sqrt{n+1+\pi f\left(n+1\right)},
$$
Hence
$$
f\left(1\right)=\sqrt{2+\pi f\left(2\right)}, \ f\left(2\right)=\sqrt{3+\pi f\left(3\right)} \Rightarrow f\left(1\right)=\sqrt{2+\pi\sqrt{3+f\left(3\right)}}
$$
which means you search for $f\left(1\right)$.
$$
f\left(n+1\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(f\left(n\right)^2-n-1\right)
$$

Comment: I dont think so, wolfram interprets it as f(0)=0

Comment: I don t think so. However do you want to find a value to this ?

Comment: There is no value for n=0 the sequence i wrote us for n>=1

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. It is not correct, both in Matlab and WolframAlpha the sequence is not correct.                                                                                     
[link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%5Cleft(n%2B1%5Cright)%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%5E2-n-1%5Cright))                                                                                 If someone can understand how to correct your formula would be perfect, yesterday I tried but I failed